# Login form, Ajax call to PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a login form, where I want to pass data from it by Ajax, into a PHP function in another file. The purpose of this is that I want the page not to reload when the user is logging in.

Right now nothing happens when user tries to log in. Seems like access.php is not proccessing the data sent from Ajax.

Can someone tell me why this is not working? What are the possible causes?

index.html:

```
      <div class="login-form">
      <form method="post" action="index.php">
          <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username...">
          <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password...">
          <button id="button" type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>

      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#button').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var username = $('#username').val();
          var password = $('#password').val();
          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'resources/includes/access.php',
              data: {
                func: 'loginSubmit',
                usernamePHP: username,
                passwordPHP: password
               },
              success: function(response) {
                  $('#result').html(response);
              }
          });
      });
      </script>
  </div>
```

access.php:

```
function loginSubmit(){
  require '../dbh.inc.php';
  $mailuid = $_POST['usernamePHP'];
  $password = $_POST['passwordPHP'];
  if(empty($mailuid) || empty($password)){
    header("Location: ../../index.php?error=emptyfields");
    exit();
  }
  else{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers=? OR emailUsers=?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
      header("Location: ../../index.php?error=sqlerror");
      exit();
    }
    else{
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $mailuid, $password);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
      if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $pwdcheck = password_verify($password, $row['pwdUsers']);
        if($pwdcheck == false) {
          header("Location: ../../index.php");
          exit();
        }
        else if($pwdcheck == true) {
          session_start();
          $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['idUsers'];
          $_SESSION['userUid'] = $row['uidUsers'];
          header("Location: ../../index.php?login=success");
          exit();
        }
        else{
          header("Location: ../../index.php");
          exit();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: add the end of the function just put `loginSubmit()` outside the function

Comment: What debugging have you done? Can you echo the post values? Are you sure that function is being called?

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), adding the function name as a data property as you are, doesn't call that function;

> data
>   Type: PlainObject or String or Array

When you call access.php, the file simply contains a function definition, you're not actually calling it.

So you have two options. Either call the function by adding `loginSubmit()` after the function (at the end of access.php),  or remove the code on access.php from a function entirely.